# How to stop time, at the time when the specified time has been exhausted in 'jQuery Countdown'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here I use an 'Ajax Request', when the specified time has run out.

The problem is at the time the time's up, 
This 'Ajax Request' keeps running every second

This my 'AJAX CODE'

```
var startdate = '2017-05-15 12:00:00 PM',
    enddate = '2017-05-15 13:00:00 PM';
    $('.<?=$fTWU?>').countdown(enddate, {elapse: true})
    .on('update.countdown', function(event) {
      if (!event.elapsed) {
        $(this).html(event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'));
      } else {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'pages/ajax_request.php',
          method: 'post',
          data: {'book': 'mathematics'},
          success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
          }
        });
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **.on('finish.countdown', function(event) {**
like this,

```
$("#youid").countdown("yourTimeHere").on('update.countdown', function(event) {

});
.on('finish.countdown', function(event) {
      //Your ajax code here
});
```

Comment: According to docs, it seems that it cannot be applyed in elapse mode: `Be aware that no finish event will be dispatched at this mode!` But if there are no reasons fot TS to use that mode, your answer is great

Comment: It's Work @Zaid Bin Khalid :D, Very Good, Thx for you help :)